# Apply a css style to an interpolation parameterusing vue-i18n

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, string-interpolation, vue-i18n

I'm using vue-i18n in order to add the internalization support to my application.
I'm not able to understand if it's possible to apply a style to a specific interpolation parameter.
E.g.
Suppose that I have this title:

Hello **Bob**, welcome back!

and as html code I have:

```
<h1>Hello <span class="name_lbl">{{name}}</span>, welcome back!</h1>
```

Using vue-i18n with the interpolation this becom something like this:

```
<h1>{{ $t("hello_message", { name: "Bob" }) }}</h1>
```

The question is: How can I apply a style on the interpolation parameter in order to have, for example, the name in bold?

**** **EDIT** ****

Using the suggestion by Nikola I updated my code in this way:

```
<i18n v-t="'home.hello_message'" tag="h2">
   <template v-slot:name>
     <span id="myClass">{{ name }}</span>
   </template>
</i18n>
```

and my messages like:

```
{
  "home": {
    "hello_message": "Hello {name}, welcome back!",
    }
}
```

The result is that I'm able to see the text "Hello , welcome back!" without the filled parameter {name}.

If I try to print into a different tag the value of {{name}} I'm able to see it correctly.

Please note also that, I'm using:

<i18n **v-t**="'home.hello_message'" tag="h2">

instead of `path` (with path dasn't works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved in this way.

```
<i18n-t keypath="home.hello_message" tag="h2">
   <template v-slot:name>
      <span class="myClass">{{ name }}</span>
   </template>
</i18n-t>
```

[slots-syntax-usage for Vue3](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/component.html#slots-syntax-usage)

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [Component interpolation - Slots syntax usage](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/interpolation.html#slots-syntax-usage), something like:

```
<i18n path="hello_message" tag="p">
  <template v-slot:name>
    <span class="name_lbl">{{ name }}</span>
  </template>
</i18n>
```